# How To Convert Sql Query to Linq Which contans Subquery

Tags: c#, sql, linq, subquery

My Query as Follows

```
   `Select * from daps_user_activity where Userid In (Select Userid from daps_portaluser  where EMR_ID = 24855) `
```

What is the equivalent query in linq please help me...

Comment: It will be much easier if you revise your original query to JOIN the two tables instead of using a subquery.

Comment: Check this link

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51339/how-can-you-handle-an-in-sub-query-with-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it's better that you use a `join` in this instance, instead of a sub-query:

```
var results = (from a in daps_user_activity
              join u in daps_portaluser on a.Userid equals u.Userid
              where u.EMR_ID == 24855
              select a).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use this:

```
var results = (from a in daps_user_activity
               from u in daps_portaluser
               where u.EMR_ID == 24855 
               && a.Userid == u.Userid
               select a).ToList()
```

To me, it shows more clearly the main query and the subquery.

Credit goes to @Bruno Brant at [Convert SQL Query (with Correlated Subquery) to LINQ in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248193/convert-sql-query-with-correlated-subquery-to-linq-in-c-sharp?rq=1)